# Limit size of input with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap and i created many screen.
I found component take a lot of space.

```
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Urgence</div>
       <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="memberEmergencyContact" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact en cas d'urgence</label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memberEmergencyContact" name="emergencyContactName" placeholder="Entrer le contact en cas d'urgence">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="emergencyPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tél</label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emergencyPhone" name="emergencyPhone">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

a link of the image
[a link of the image](http://picpaste.com/urgence_zone-QAL8OGjl.jpeg)

I would like to reduce size of the input, very to long.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized what you want.

Define a **col-md-9** or either **lg, xs** or **sm**, inside  `<div class="form-group">`. So, beside the form group,  `<div class="col-md-9 form-group">`. Otherwise it will always be at maximum width. Also, you may want to omit form-group or redefine it somewhere else.

---

<strike>Use **col-lg-9** for Desktop (**large screen**) and so on. You have only defined **sm** (**small screen**). Also use **md** (**medium screen**) and **xs** (**extra small screen**).</strike>

So change your div to this, in:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memberEmergencyContact" name="emergencyContactName" placeholder="Entrer le contact en cas d'urgence">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using the whole row that's why the panel take a lot of space. To make it smaller you have to set specific column width.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Urgence</div>
       <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="memberEmergencyContact" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact en cas d'urgence</label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memberEmergencyContact" name="emergencyContactName" placeholder="Entrer le contact en cas d'urgence">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="emergencyPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tél</label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emergencyPhone" name="emergencyPhone">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```